# Compact subsets of bounded functions

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification, compactness

If $X$ is a non-empty set then let $\ell_\infty(X)$ denote the space of all bounded functions on $X$ equipped with the supremum norm. Then I claim that :

> A subset $\mathscr{A}$ of $\ell_\infty(X)$ is totally bounded if and only if it is bounded, and given $\epsilon>0$ we can find a finite partition $(A_i)_i$ of $X$ such that for all $f\in\mathscr{A}$ we have $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ for all $x,y\in A_i$ for each $i$.

**Proof:** Suppose $\mathscr{A}$ is totally bounded. Then given $\epsilon>0$ there exist finitely many functions $f_1,\dots,f_l$ such that for each $f\in\mathscr{A}$ we have $||{f-f_k}||_\infty<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for some $k$. And since simple functions are dense in $\ell_\infty(X)$ we can assume each $f_i$ to be simple i.e. assuming only finitely many distinct values. Let $a_{i1},\dots,a_{im_i}$ be the values attained by $f_i$ and define $A_{ij}=f_i^{-1}(a_{ij})$. Each $(A_{ij})_j$ is a finite partition of $X$. On each $A_{ij}$ the function $f_i$ is constant; although a different $f_p$ may not be. Now pick one set from each partition and take their intersection. Do this for all possible choices. This will give us another finite partition $(A_i)_i$ of $X$. By construction, each $f_i$ is constant on every $A_j$. Then for all $i$ and all $x,y\in A_i$ we have $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq|f(x)-f_k(x)|+|f_k(x)-f_k(y)|+|f_k(y)-f(y)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+0+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$$

Conversely let the above conditions hold. Let $||{f}||_\infty<K$ for all $f\in\mathscr{A}$. Given $\epsilon>0$ we can find $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $m\epsilon>K$. Consider the collection of simple functions $$\bigg\{\sum\limits_i j_i\epsilon\chi_{A_i}:j_i=0,\pm 1,\dots,\pm m\ \forall\:i\bigg\}$$
This collection is finite.
Now for all $f$ and each $i$ we have $$\sup\limits_{A_i}f-\inf\limits_{A_i}f\leq\epsilon$$
There is a unique integer $j_i$ with $-m\leq j_i\leq m$ such that $$(j_i-1)\epsilon\leq\inf\limits_{A_i}f<j_i\epsilon$$ So that $$(j_i-1)\epsilon\leq\inf\limits_{A_i}f\leq\sup\limits_{A_i}f<(j_i+1)\epsilon$$ Which gives $$(j_i-1)\epsilon\leq f\leq(j_i+1)\epsilon$$ in $A_i$.
i.e. $$|f-j_i\epsilon|\leq\epsilon$$ in $A_i$.
Therefore $$|| f-\sum\limits_ij_i\epsilon\chi_{A_i}||_\infty\leq\epsilon$$
This shows that $\mathscr{A}$ is totally bounded.

Is this alright? Can it be improved/shortened?